# What can cause "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address"?

Tags: asp.net, email, message

What can cause the error "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address"?

Source code line that causes the error:

```
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("txtEmail.Text"));
```

Answer (score 16):

```
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("txtEmail.Text"));
```

is the problem. txtEmail.Text is not an e-mail address. If that's a text file that's a list of e-mails, you're going to need to open it and read it and pass them in one by one.

If it's referring to a textbox, take the quotes around it off. Like this:

```
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text));
```

Answer (score 14):

For me, the problem was using semi-colon(;) to seperate multiple emails.
Once I change it to comma(,) it works.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

The issue on the code above might have occured due to

```
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("txtEmail.Text"));
```

You might be clear that here "txtEmail.Text" appears as a string but not the mailing address to whom the mail is to be send. So code should be replaced with

```
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text));
```

and sometimes the error like "**The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address**" might also occur due to use of improper string.As even I faced it.

**Basically I was working in email sending task using the ASP.Net. The main issue for me was sending mail to multiple users**. Firstly, I retrieved the email address from database and **used " ; " so as to separate the multiple email addresses**. Because while sending the email to multiple users, in regular basis we use  semicolon i.e. " ;"

Everything seemed ok but after compilation I got the error "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address".

**After a bit analysis, I came to know that instead of using the " ; "  we should use " , " so as to separate multiple email address while sending mails . This is the formatted string for separating the emails.**

For Details visit: http://kopila.com.np

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

both the sender and recipient address need to be a valid email address format. eg. user@domain.com

Answer (score 1):

Guess what the issue was for us?

Trailing spaces. For some reason, when you use a multi-line text box, spaces are added to the front of the string.

When we used Trim on the string, it worked fine.

Comment: For us, the issue was new lines (\n). After removing that, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I was creating the message with the recipient and the sender already in it, but it returned the following error:

`The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address`

The problematic code was as follows:

```
MailMessage objMsg = new MailMessage(regEmail.Text.ToString(), "me@mysite.com");
```

I fixed the issue by replacing that code with this:

```
MailMessage objMsg = new MailMessage();
objMsg.From = new MailAddress(regEmail.Text.ToString());
objMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("me@mysite.com"));
```

It is also helpful to use a regular expression validator in your user control to make sure the address is valid, you can use the following code for asp:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regex1" ControlToValidate="regEmail" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address" ValidationExpression="^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$" ValidationGroup="regGroup" runat="server" Display="None" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Or if you'd prefer to validate the email in C# then you can use this as also stated by S Fadhel Ali:

```
public static bool IsValidEmail(String Email)
{
    if( Email != null && Email != "" )
        return Regex.IsMatch(Email, @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" );
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the following format.

```
Dim myMail As New Net.Mail.MailMessage(New MailAddress(strFrom), New MailAddress(strTo))
```