# Unable to attach email to MailMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, mailmessage

I am trying to generate a list of emails from sql then use that list to attach each email address to a mail message. I am getting:

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail
>   address.

What am I doing wrong? This error is happening at the foreach within the Page_Load. When looking at the mailAddress variable it is showing the email addresses normally as it should "johndoe@gmail.com"

I've tried a few suggestions like changing the mail add to:

```
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailAddress.ToString()));
```

but that didn't work.

```
public class Supervisor
{
   public string Email { get; set; }
}

public List<Supervisor> LoadSupervisors(int ID)
{
   var listOfEmails = new List<Supervisor>();
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
   {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"", conn2);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
      conn.Open();
      SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      while (rdr.Read())
      {
         var supervisor = new Supervisor();
         supervisor.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
         listOfEmails.Add(supervisor);
      }
    }
    return listOfEmails;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //----- Bunch of code that isn't related
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      var listOfEmails = new List<Supervisor>();
      listOfEmails = LoadSupervisors(Convert.ToInt32(rdr["UserID"]));

      MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
      SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient("");
      foreach (var mailAddress in listOfEmails)
      {
          msg.To.Add(mailAddress.ToString());
      }
      //----- Bunch of code that isn't related
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757001/the-specified-string-is-not-in-the-form-required-for-an-e-mail-address)

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy Not a duplicate, I tried everything in that post prior to submitting this one. I am dealing with a list not a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should get `.Email` property of your `mailAddress` instead of itself. Because `mailAddress` is a `Supervisor`, not a `string` or something.

Try as;

```
msg.To.Add(mailAddress.Email.ToString());
```

But of course, we don't know anything about `Email` type, I assume it returns this mail address as a string since you said you see it on debugger or something.